# WordPress get_posts returns nothing when called during "init"

Tags: wordpress

My plugin uses this function to return an array of all posts of a custom post type ('100q_quote'):

```
function get_posts_by_category($category_filter) {
    if($category_filter != 'default') {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => '100q_taxonomy_category',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => $category_filter
            )
        );
        $args = array('post_type' => '100q_quote', 'tax_query' => $tax_query);
    }
    else {
        $args = array('post_type' => '100q_quote');
    }
    $postArray = get_posts($args);
    return $postArray;
}
```

Then this function selects one post at random from the array and returns the body content:

```
function get_random_quote($category_filter) {
    $postArray = get_posts_by_category($category_filter);
    if(count($postArray) > 0) {
        $randPostNum = mt_rand(0, count($postArray) - 1);
        $randQuote = $postArray[$randPostNum]->post_content;
        return $randQuote;
    }
    return "";
}
```

That function gets called from this action hook which puts the selected text into an option where it can be called from anywhere:

```
function update_quote_option($quote){
    update_option('100quotes_random_quote', $quote);
}

function set_random_quote_option() {
    $category_filter = get_option('100quotes_category_filter', 'default');
    $randQuote = get_random_quote($category_filter);
    update_quote_option($randQuote);
}
add_action('init', 'set_random_quote_option');
```

And is finally output here (in this case, when the "random" display option is selected):

```
function add_quote_to_posts($text) {
    return add_styling(get_current_quote_text()).$text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_quote_to_posts');

function get_current_quote_text() {
    $selection = get_option('100quotes_display_option', 'none');
    $category_filter = get_option('100quotes_category_filter', 'default');

    if($selection == 'none')
        return '';
    else if($selection == 'first')
        $quote_text = get_most_recent_post($category_filter);
    else if($selection == 'random')
        //$quote_text = get_random_quote($category_filter); //This works, but doesn't allow uniform selection.
        $quote_text = get_option('100quotes_random_quote', 'Error: Random quote option not set.');
    else
        $quote_text = get_post($selection)->{'post_content'};
    return $quote_text;
}
```

But the array returned by the get_posts_by_category function is always empty. I know the logic works because the same function is used successfully to get the text for the "get_most_recent_post" display option, although that function is not hooked into an action and does not update an option.

Also, I can directly call the get_random_quote function from the "random" branch in get_current_quote_text (see commented out line) and queries successfully, but doesn't give me the desired result.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The problem was hooking this function into the "init" hook.

Init fires before the taxonomy query is initialized, thus the solution was to choose an action which happens after this initialization. I chose "send_headers" because I wanted WordPress to update the option after the user submits a form with the display options.

```
add_action('send_headers', 'set_random_quote_option');
```